# Controlling iPhone App Flow During Table View Animations

Tags: iphone, multithreading, animation, uitableview

In my application I would like to be able to wait until table view animations (deleting table view rows) were complete before executing part of my application. I was wondering if there would be any way to wait or pause my application until the these animations were complete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After the deletion is completed, your tableview should send the tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath: message to its delegate.  If your delegate responds to that message, you can put your app code (or a call to the class that executes it) in that method.

Apple has more info on tableview inserts and deletes here:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html